# How to retrieve id's and names of all fields of a particular type from html to Django views

Tags: html, django

I have a html form with a list of input fields with id's, names and values. Is there a way I can get these values in Django views by only mentioning the input type. For example :  get the id's and values of all input elements with type text.

Comment: can you show us code snippets of your project, for us to understand it better ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can't access to `id`s from your server code, unless you have some Javascript code to analyze the DOM and send them to the server. Names and values are already sent to the server on a GET or POST request.

Comment: use javascript and sent it to Django views through AJAX..